# mysqli_real_escape_string() PHP error inserting a file into a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im trying to insert a file into a table but im getting the following error with the code bellow:

**Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given**

here is my php code:

```
<?php


if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    // Make sure the file was sent without errors
    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {

        $sql_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "teste", "localhost"); 
        mysql_select_db("skande5_form", $sql_connection);

        $nameFile = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $mime = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
        $size = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);
        $data = mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
```

does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: 1. Note the error message. 2. Go to http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string and see what the other parameter should be.

Comment: Don't mix `mysql_connect` and `mysqli_real_escape_string`! They are from **different** libraries.

Comment: @Quentin how should i write this then?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @Oliveira — Pick either mysql_* or mysqli_* (hint: Don't use the obsolete, deprecated, rubbish mysql_*) or PDO and consult the manuals for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your are mixing both `mysql_*` and `mysqli_` function, correct syntax for `mysql` is `mysql_real_escape_string`

> mysql_select_db and mysql_connect --> mysql
>
> mysqli_real_escape_string --> mysqli

I would kindly suggest to use mysqli and use prepared statment to avaiod any risk of mysql injection have a look here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).